# How do I capture dask-worker console logs in a file?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

In the below, I want to capture "dask_client_log_msg" and other task-logs in one file and "dask_worker_log_msg" and other client-logs in a separate file. As obviously client will run in a separate process altogether than the worker. So I need one process should log all its message in a separate file. Thanks!

```py
def my_task():
  print("dask_worker_log_msg")
  ...

client = Client(<scheduler_address>)

future = client.submit(my_task)
print("dask_client_log_msg")
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get logs from your workers with the [Client.get_worker_logs](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.Client.get_worker_logs) method.  You can also download logs from the dashboard in the `info` pane.

Comment: Thanks.! Although I tried this api, but what I am getting is the dask-worker starting logs and not the logs which is logged by the task running inside the worker. How to get the the running task logs in a file.? is my doubt. Sorry, if my question has created any sort of confusion.

Comment: There is currently no mechanism to capture stdout and pipe it back to your client process.

Comment: So Dask does not support custom logging? As a workaround, you can set up your logs as warning or higher (e.g. `logger.warning("This is an info message that was set to warning so that it can be retrieved from Dask")`), so they're sent to stderr and can be retrieved from Dask (e.g. if you're running dask from a shell, you can do it like this `dask-worker your_scheduler_addr &>> /path/to/log.log`).

Comment: Dask just uses the standard Python logging module, which pipes results to stderr as you say.  We don't do anything special on our own here.  Typically this is handled by infrastructure systems like Yarn or Kubernetes.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't yet use any additional infrastructure on top of Dask, so I need to figure out a way to get the logs myself. The use case is simple: I have some log entries in my script -- how can I retrieve them? I seem to be missing some basic knowledge, because to my understanding I should get the logger using `logging.getLogger`, do `logger.info("some info")` and see this in worker logs. This works for warning and higher levels, but not for info. I have set info as the level for workers and scheduler in dask config and am not sure where else to look.

Comment: @MRocklin Is this still the case, or could it be done via a callback (say) or some other mechanism?

Comment: @MRocklin Apologies, just discovered the bleeding-edge https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/_modules/distributed/client.html#Client.forward_logging - is that right?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution if you're trying to implement a Dask cluster and need the logs from all jobs that it runs (including logs from your scripts from print or logger.info):

1. Add a redirect in your bash script starting the worker:
   `dask-worker >> dask_worker.log 2>&1`
2. In your script, set your logger to dask.distributed, like so:
   `logger = logging.getLogger("distributed.worker")`
3. Configure the log format in `.config/dask/distributed.yaml`

See also [How to capture logs from workers from a Dask-Yarn job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633097/how-to-capture-logs-from-workers-from-a-dask-yarn-job)