# How to capture logs from workers from a Dask-Yarn job?

Tags: dask

I have tried using the following in `~/.config/dask/distributed.yaml` and `~/.config/dask/yarn.yaml`,

```
logging-file-config: "/path/to/config.ini"
```

or

```
logging:
  version: 1
  disable_existing_loggers: false

  root:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [consoleHandler]

  handlers:
    consoleHandler:
      class: logging.StreamHandler
      level: INFO
      formatter: sample_formatter
      stream: ext://sys.stderr

  formatters:
    sample_formatter:
      format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
```

and then in my function that gets evaluated at the worker:

```
import logging
from distributed.worker import logger
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_yarn import YarnCluster

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@dask.delayed
def worker_func(args):
    logger.info("This will show up in the worker logs")
    log.info("This does not show up in worker logs")
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag_1 = {'worker_func': (worker_func, arg_1)}
    tasks = dask.get(dag_1, 'load-1')

    log.info("This also shows up in logs, and custom formatted)
    cluster = YarnCluster()
    client = Client(cluster)
    dask.compute(tasks)
```

When I try to view the yarn logs using:

```
yarn logs -applicationId {application_id}
```

I do not see the log from `log.info` inside `worker_func`, but I do see the logs from `distributed.worker.logger` and from outside that function on the console. I also tried using [client.get_worker_logs()](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.Client.get_worker_logs), but that returned an empty dictionary. Is there a way to see customized logs from inside the function that gets evaluated at a worker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot going on in this question, so I'm going to answer "How do I configure logging for dask-yarn workers" and hope everything else becomes clear by answering that.

Dask's configuration system is loaded locally on the machine you start a dask cluster from (usually the edge node). This configuration is *not* distributed to the workers automatically, you're responsible for doing that yourself. You have a few options here:

- Have admin/IT put configuration in `/etc/dask/` on every node, which will affect all users.
- Bundle configuration with your packaged environment. Dask will load configuration from `{prefix}/etc/dask/`, where `prefix` is `sys.prefix`.

For example, if you have a conda environment at `/path/to/environment`, you'd do the following to bundle the configuration

```
# Create the configuration directory in the environment
mkdir -p /path/to/environment/etc/dask/
# Add your configuration to this directory
mv config.yaml /path/to/environment/etc/dask/config.yaml
# Package the environment
conda pack -p /path/to/environment -o environment.tar.gz
```

Any configuration values set in `config.yaml` will now be available on all the worker nodes. An example configuration file setting some logging configuration would be:

```
logging:
  version: 1

  root:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [consoleHandler]

  handlers:
    consoleHandler:
      class: logging.StreamHandler
      level: INFO
      formatter: sample_formatter
      stream: ext://sys.stderr

  formatters:
    sample_formatter:
      format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
```

Logs from completed dask-yarn applications can be retrieved using the YARN cli at

```
yarn logs -applicationId <application-id>
```

Logs for *running* dask-yarn applications can be retrieved using [`client.get_worker_logs()`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.get_worker_logs). Note that these logs will *only contain logs written to the `distributed.worker` logger*. You cannot write to your own logger and have them appear in the output of `client.get_worker_logs()`. To write to this logger, get it via

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("distributed.worker")
logger.info("Writing with the worker logger")
```

Any logger appropriately configured to log to `stdout` or `stderr` will appear in the logs accessed via the yarn CLI, but only the `distributed.worker` logger output will also be available to `get_worker_logs()`.

---

*Side note*

> I have tried using the following in ~/.config/dask/distributed.yaml and ~/.config/dask/yarn.yaml

The name of the config files doesn't matter, dask loads all `yaml` files in all config directories and merges their contents. For more information please read [the configuration docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response, really appreciate it! I will try this out and report back here, but is this the only way to get logging to work from dask-yarn workers? Editing a conda environment doesn't seem like a very clean solution to me.

Comment: This is currently the only way to provide custom configuration to workers. Logging always works, you'd only need to package the configuration with the conda environment if you want to change the default configuration in some way.

Comment: I followed the exact same steps above, but it didn't seem to affect the results in any way. `logger.info` still appears un-configured and `log.info` still does not appear in the YARN logs.Here are the steps I followed:
1) mkdir -p /path/to/environment/etc/dask/
2) cp config.yaml /path/to/environment/etc/dask/config.yaml
3) conda pack -p /path/to/environment -o environment.tar.gz

And then creating my YARN cluster as:
`cluster = YarnCluster(environment="path/to/environment.tar.gz")`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Correction: it worked but only if I removed other keys, apart from `logging`, from `config.yaml`. I had an extra key `inputs` in `config.yaml` at the same level of `logging`, which I didn't expect to interfere with Dask reading the logging configuration. Should this key interfere with Dask reading the configuration from the `logging` key?

Comment: Was it under `logging`, or at the same level as `logging`? Things work fine for me with additional keys in the file, provided they're not under `logging`.

Comment: Worked for me as well, perhaps I forgot to re-package the environment after editing the file, sorry, my bad. Marking this as answered. Thank you so much for your help! Hope to see a slightly better solution in the future...